# What is the difference between field and group in algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra

What is the difference between a field and a group in algebra?

Could someone briefly explain it?

Comment: Have you read the definitions of the two kinds of objects?

Answer (score 14):

This is more of a rejoinder to PEV's response as it existed before the edit. One can think of "subtraction" as an operation separate from addition, though rather than consider the binary operation, one usually considers the *unary* operation that maps an element to its additive inverse (it has nicer properties than subtraction, which is not associative, and it automatically captures the idea that the additive inverse is unique).

In fact, from the point of view of Universal Algebra, we want a group to have **three** operations: a binary operation $\cdot$ (that corresponds to the group product), a unary operation ${}^{-1}$ (that maps every element to its inverse), and a zeroary operation $e$ (distinguished element). Then the "axioms" of a group can be stated as identities of the operations:

1. $(a\cdot b)\cdot c = a\cdot(b\cdot c)$;
2. $e\cdot a = a\cdot e = a$;
3. $a\cdot a^{-1} = a^{-1}\cdot a = e$.

Being expressible as identities has all sorts of nice consequences. Consequently, universal algebraists will consider a group as a set together with three operations.

Fields are more problematical, though. You start the same way: with two binary operations $+$ and $\times$; a unary operation $-$; two zeroary operations $0$ and $1$, and the axioms that describe these operations. Multiplicative inverses, however, are not defined via an operation, because $0$ does not have a multiplicative inverse. Instead, they must be defined via a *partial* operations, so fields are not "algebras" within the sense of universal algebra, but rather they are *partial algebras*. We know that fields cannot be defined as algebras with operations, because if they could then the category of fields (or even of fields of a given characteristic) with field morphisms would necessarily have categorical products, and they do not.

The theory of partial algebras is far more difficult than the theory of algebras. I seem to recall Brian Davey and David Clark, in their book **Natural Dualities for the Working Mathematician** mentioning that one can prove a lot of very nice and powerful "theorems" about partial algebras if one forgets some of the problems (e.g., if $f\colon A\to B$ is a homomorphism of partial algebras, then $f(A)$ need not be a partial-subalgebra of $B$; though this is particularly problematical when one consider relational algebras and relational partial algebras, where we have relations in addition to operations).

Comment: @Arturo: If we use the definition that the morphisms preserve the operations, then a group has 2 operations? But if we look at a "structural" definition, then it would have 3?

Comment: @PEV: No, in this context, groups have three operations, period. Morphisms are required to take the image of a product into a product of images; the image of the inverse into the inverse of the image, and the distinguished element to the distinguished element. Where do you get "2 operations"?

Comment: @PEV: For instance, in the context of monoids, that have two operations (a binary operation and a zeroary operation), morphisms are required to take the identity to the identiy (these are the "monoid morphisms", as opposed to semigroup homomorphisms between monoids).

Comment: @Arturo: Isn't it implied by the first two conditions that distinguished elements go to distinguished elements (e.g. $f(x^{-1}x)=f(x)^{-1}f(x)=1=f(1)$)? So it is similar to an isomorphism (not a morphism).

Comment: @PEV: It doesn't matter. If you are dealing with groups as universal algebras, you have to respect all the operations. The fact that a semigroup homomorphism between groups happens to be a group homomorphism is a special situation that has to do with groups and the identities they satisfy, not with the general set-up. (As an aside: there *is* a way of defining "groups" with a single ternary operation, but in that case you don't have a nice functor to semigroups and back). And, no, not "similar to an isomorphism." Please read up a bit on universal algebra; e.g., Bergman's book is a good intro.

Comment: @PEV: The problem with what you write, by the way, is that if you view groups as having only two operations, multiplication and identity, then you cannot even **write** the equation $f(x^{-1}x) = f(x)^{-1}f(x) =1$, because this refers to all three operations; if you don't have the "distinguished element operation", you cannot write it down. There are inverse semigroups that are not groups, after all.

Comment: @PEV: In short; morphisms are required to respect all three operations, it's a theorem that in fact it is enough to check they are semigroup homomorphism (because the forgetful functor from groups to semigroups is full: every semigroup homomorphism between two groups is a group homomorphism). Think about the case of rational vector spaces: a function between $\mathbb{Q}$-vector spaces is linear if and only if it is additive: homogeneity will follow "automatically"; but linear transformations between $\mathbb{Q}$-vector spaces do not respect only one operation, and Q-vector spaces aren't groups

Comment: @Arturo: no there isn't!  You need at least two operations for a group.  The ternary by itself gives you a heap and you need the unary operation to give you a group.

Comment: @Andrew: I'll have to go check B.H. Neumann's result and verify (though you might have been clearer on what "No there isn't" refered to). You may be correct.

Comment: @Arturo: Sorry, I meant that you can't find a presentation of "Groups" that only uses a tenary operation.  You must have a unary operation since the empty set isn't a group.  As far as functors go then it doesn't matter how you present them since functors and morphisms make no distinction between how a variety of algebras is _presented_ and all the derived operations that arise.  I second the recommendation to read Bergman's book, by the way.  That's where I learnt this stuff from.

Comment: @Andrew: I think you mean, then, that one needs a zeroary operation, not a unary one (unary operations don't exclude the empty set). But that's a good point; I'm definitely misremembering something.

Comment: @Arturo: Yes, that's right, I do mean _zeroary_ (ugly word!).  My apologies for the confusion.

Comment: @Andrew: You can always use "nullary" instead...

Comment: @Arturo: and that's supposed to be _better_??  I suspect that this is one case where the longer "operation of arity 0" should almost always be used.

Comment: @Andrew: You know, a lot of people have the same gut reaction dislike to the word "arity" itself... (-;

Comment: I am reading through this and I am a bit confused. I learned that a group axioms need only to rely on two operations (a binary $\otimes$ and the neutral element $e$).
The existence of an inverse follows from 
$\exists! b: a\otimes b=b\otimes a= e$. (Indeed it is sufficent to assume that $\exists b:...$ since the uniqueness follows from the group axioms.) Using this axiom, we can define a unary inverse function:
$inv(a) =$ that $b$ such that $a\otimes b = e$.
(This definition is only allowed because of the uniqueness of $b$.)

Comment: @Hauke: If you want to describe groups via **operations** and **identities** (as opposed to axioms), then the inverse cannot be given by an axiom; it has to be described in terms of operations and universal equalities. From the point of view of universal algebra, you cannot use axioms that have existential quantifiers. That's the same reason why you don't define the neutral element via an axiom (which you could as well). A group is an algebra (in the sense of universal algebra) with **three** operations: the binary product, the unary inverse, and the nullary identity, (cont)

Comment: @HaukeStrasdat (cont) that satisfy certain identities: associativity of the binary operation, the relation between the unary and binary operations (identity 'axiom') and the relation between the binary, unary, and nullary operation (the 'inverse' axiom). There are many ways of defining "group", but this is the way to define it within the context of universal algebra. There are **no** axioms whatsoever, just operations and identities.

Comment: @HaukeStrasdat: The fact that the "usual" way of describing a group (via a single binary operation and a bunch of axioms) also yields a group in the sense of universal algebra is essentially what you write: the axioms tell you that $e$ is unique (so you can define a nullary operation), and that inverses are uniquely determined by the element in question (so you can define them as a unary operation). Conversely, a group defined as in universal algebra will satisfy the "axioms" from the 'usual' way of describing a book because of the identities that are required.

Answer (score 4):

I feel this question is too broad for MSE, and could easily be answered by using a common search engine.  Briefly: A field has two operations and is always commutative.  See [Definiton of Group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_%28mathematics%29#Definition) and [Definition of Field](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_%28mathematics%29#Definition_and_illustration).

Comment: Looking at PEV's response, I think of division an multiplication as the same operation, similarly for subtraction/addition.

Answer (score 3):

Another attempt to answer this question in more basic terms:

**Groups** and **Fields** are both important subjects of contemporary algebra. They are now recognized as strongly related, and arising in many situations :

- **fields** contain two different **groups** as substructure that work together nicely
- so, in order to prove that something is a **field**, you can first try to prove it contains these two **groups**, then prove other further properties (such as distributivity).

But originally, they came up from different questions.

- **Groups** arose from the study of substitutions (permutations) of symbols motivated by the theory of equations and the study of symmetry of geometric figures. They were then recognized as present in many aspects of mathematics.
- **Fields** arose as the generalization of the properties of the real numbers in regard to addition and multiplication, the usage of coordinates, and the expressive powers of formulas using symbols and basic operations.

But now mathematicians see them as both fundamentally linked together and to the ideas of *number systems*, *sets of solutions of equations*, *solvability*, *the general concept of space*, *equations of physics*.  One particular kind of object which is very accessible to the beginner and can be an introduction to the links between the two are called: **Finite Fields** and one way to construct them is from the idea of the remainder of the division of an integer by a prime: in $29 = 7*4 + 1$, $1$ is called *the remainder* of the *quotient* of $29$ by $7$.

There is a broader concept relative to **fields**, called a **ring**, and there is the more global concept of **algebra** or **algebraic structure** which covers groups, rings and fields and many more. See also **Varieties**.

To have a broader idea of this family, you can lookup **Lie algebras**, **Jordan algebras**, **Hopf algebras**, **von Neuman algebras**, and further study a branch of algebra called *Universal Algebra*.

Comment: Groups actually arose *in* the study of equations. I don't know in what sense *ring* is a parent concept to *groups*, really.

Comment: My formulation -- I will try to edit it, may give a false impression. Groups actually arose first under this name both in the study of equations designed and used by Galois as "Groups of substitutions" operating on **symbols** and by Cauchy as well, at the same time, operating also on points of geometrical figures designed by letters.

Comment: @Mariano: About rings, the problem between us is perhaps the meaning of "parent" here. I see at least two reasons to consider them close parents : one is the embedded group in a ring and another one is the fundamental way to see a finite group for instance, as a $\Z$-module or a $F_q$-module. It is the basis of modern proofs of many important results of group theory.

Comment: You probably mean "relative" instead of "parents" ("being a parent of" is not a symmetric relation, so that saying that two concepts are "close parents" does not make a lot of sense :) )

Comment: In any case, that use of "parent" is rather strange. Topological spaces are also on the basis of many important results of group theory, yet it would be quite strange to say that groups and topological spaces are "close parents".

Comment: @Mariano: you are right the confusion stems from the meaning of "parent" in french which is more inclusive than in modern english. I will edit my text again, thanks for your remark. But I maintain that there is a stronger and genetic link between groups and rings than between (to take your own example), topological spaces and groups, even if in my opinion, the latter link is quite close too.

Answer (score 0):

As Arturo points out, "a group has three operations with signature (2,1,0) (binary, unary, zeroary), while a field has two binary, one unary, two zeroary operations and one unary partial operation" (5 operations and 1 partial operation). A group has to satisfy (i) closure (ii) associativity, (iii) identity and (iv) invertibility. A field has to satisfy these as well and also have distributivity of multiplication over addition and commutativity. We can also talk about [field extensions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_extension) and [group extensions](http://terrytao.wordpress.com/2010/01/23/some-notes-on-group-extensions/). As Tao notes, one usually talks about field extensions as embedding a field $F$ into a larger field $K$ that has $F$ as a subspace. Group extensions, on the other hand, are defined by covering. That is, we cover a group $G$ by another group $G'$ that has $G$ has a quotient.

Comment: If you are going to declare subtraction and division "operations" on a field separate from addition and multiplication (which I think is terrible, pedagogically), why doesn't a group have a second operation taking $a$ and $b$ to $ab^{-1}$? For that matter, why doesn't a field have a fifth operation, taking $a$ and $b$ to $a^5-b$? Those are operations, too... unless you feel like one should "rule out" operations that aren't essential to the definition. Like subtraction and division, both of which can be characterized using only the axioms for addition and multiplication.

Comment: While you can argue that subtraction is an operation (or better, following the universal algebra model, that "additive inverse" is a unary operation), you'll have a hard time with division (or multiplicative inverse), since it is at best a **partial** operation, not an operation. And if additive inverse is an operation for fields, then it's an operation for groups. If you *really* want to be a stickler, a group has **three** operations with signature (2,1,0) (binary, unary, zeroary), while a field has two binary, one unary, two zeroary operations and one unary partial operation.

Comment: "Closure" is subsumed under "operation".

Comment: @Zev: In fact, the operation taking $a$ and $b$ to $a^5-b$ is a "derived operation", a member of the clone of the ring. But probably not something to introduce when one is introducing groups and rings/fields, for sure...